# Webpack: Failed to load config file when using typescript@5 moduleResolution of "bundler"

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm using `typescript@5.0.2` and `webpack-cli@5.0.1` and `webpack@5.76.2`.
I tried to use the new `moduleResolution` with value `bundler` that `typescript@5` offers.
I have also configured `"type": "module"` in `package.json` file.

I have configured my `tsconfig.json` file with these values:

```json
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
```

I configured a `webpack.config.prod.ts` and I tried to build my application by running `webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.config.prod.ts`.

Then I got an error:
`[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/myProject/webpack/webpack.config.prod.ts' config`

And

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /myProject/webpack/webpack.config.prod.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:79:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:121:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:81:20)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:605:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:63:26)
    at ESMLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:480:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:34) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an ongoing issue. However it sounds like you can do the following:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/2458
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/2916

> FYI as of today for me to be able to import an ESM module (webpack
> plugin) from webpack.config.ts, I needed to add the following to the
> tsconfig.json:
>
> ```
> {   // ...   
>     "ts-node": {
>       // Tell ts-node CLI to install the --loader automatically, explained below
>       "esm": true,
>       "compilerOptions": {
>         "module": "CommonJS",
>         "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
>        }
>     }   
> },
> ```
>
> ... It's based on your responses above. "ts-node" itself works instead of TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS as already mentioned
> here, plus "esm": true replaces the need for passing --loader
> ts-node/esm to Node (see https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/imports).
>
> node: v16.14.1
> ts-node: v10.8.1
> typescript: 4.7.3
> webpack: 5.73.0
> webpack-cli: 4.10.0